# Not displaying JSON data in Jquery datatable

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, spring-mvc, datatables

I am trying to display sample data from my Java controller into the table, however, it is not rendering the data nor displaying any error messages. For the time being, I am trying to display simple mock data in JSON format...However, the table is not displaying any data nor any error messages..

I am using JSP, AngualrJS and jquery for front end, Java for backend..

This is my JSP Page table:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap" id="myTable">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>Status</th>
</tr>
</thead>
</table
```

This is my JSP page:

```
$.ajax({
url:"/home/review/",
success:function(data) {
var table = $('#myTable').DataTable( {
"data": data,
dom: "Bfrtip",
"iDisplayLength": 15,
"lengthChange": false,
"ordering": true,
"info": false,
'columnDefs': [
{
'targets': 1,
'orderable': false,
'checkboxes': {
'selectRow': true
}
}
],
'select': {
'style': 'multi'
},

    { "data": "id", "defaultContent": "" },
    { "data": "status", "defaultContent": ""}
],
});
}
});
```

This is my angularJS Controller:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('HomeController', ['DTOptionsBuilder', 'DTColumnBuilder','HomeService', '$scope', function(DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnBuilder, HomeService, $scope) {
var test_URL = '/home/review/';
var self = $scope;
var vm = this;

vm.dtOptions = HomeService.fetchList();
console.log(vm.dtOptions);
}]);
```

My angularJS service:

```
angular.module('myApp').factory(HomeService', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q){

var URL= '/home/review/';

var factory = {
        fetchList: fetchList
};

return factory;

function fetchList() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http.get(URL)
        .then(
        function (response) {
            deferred.resolve(response.data);
        },
        function(errResponse){
            console.error('Error while fetching List');
            deferred.reject(errResponse);
        }
    );
    return deferred.promise;
}
}]);
```

This is my Java backend controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/review/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String geList() throws JSONException {
logger.info("List All Controller");
System.out.println("Fetching All list...");

    JSONArray resultarray = new JSONArray();
    String resultString = "";
            JSONObject result = new JSONObject();
            result.put("id","1234");
            result.put("status", "New");
            resultarray.put(result);

        resultString = resultarray.toString(4);
        System.out.println(resultString);

    return resultString;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try JSON.parse() for your data, while passing to the DataTable.